# Encrypt two given strings

Tags: java

I'm trying to encrypt a message by the following code above.

1. Compare 2 string length and refill the short one with cycle back.
2. Convert that 2 string into a binary string.
3. XOR that 2 binary string to get another binary string.
4. convert the last binary string to hexadecimal.

Issue is on the last step. The output should be `111c0d131e1c180e1b10425655` instead of `111cd131e1c18e1b10425655`.
Why my output missing two letters 0?
Can anyone help me to fix, please?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Main
{
    public static String StringToBinary(String str) 
    {

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        char[] ch = str.toCharArray();
        for (char character : ch) 
        {
            result.append(String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(character)).replaceAll(" ", "0"));
        }
        return result.toString();

    }
    public static String XOR(String message, String password)
    {
        String tmp="";
        for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) 
        { 
            if (message.charAt(i) == password.charAt(i)) 
                tmp += "0"; 
            else
                tmp += "1"; 
        } 
        return tmp;
    }
    public static String convertBinaryToHexadecimal(String binaryStr) 
    {
        return new BigInteger(binaryStr, 2).toString(16);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int idx=0;
        String msg = "poiuytrewq123";
        String pwd = "asdfghjkl";
        for(char m:msg.toCharArray())
        {
            idx = (idx < pwd.length()) ? idx : 0;
            char p = pwd.charAt(idx);
            idx++;
            String stringOfMessageCharArray = String.valueOf(m);
            String stringOfPasswordCharArray = String.valueOf(p);
            String messageBinaryString = StringToBinary(stringOfMessageCharArray);
            String passwordBinaryString = StringToBinary(stringOfPasswordCharArray);
            String XorString = XOR(messageBinaryString,passwordBinaryString);
            String cipherText = convertBinaryToHexadecimal(XorString);
            System.out.print(cipherText);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the number you are trying to convert from binary to hex is too small to require 2 characters, so it outputs just one.

```java
public static String convertBinaryToHexadecimal(String binaryStr)
{
    String hex = new BigInteger(binaryStr, 2).toString(16);
    return hex.length() < 2 ? "0" + hex : hex;
}
```

If you change the function to this, it will put a 0 at the front of the hex if the length is less than 2, and return the right hex.